# Performance Issue with SQL Server 2008 R2 64 Bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 which is 64 bit. Recently I have been observing that there is a huge performance issue in the server. The physical capacity of the server is 28GB. This server is the data warehouse and contains tables having records more than 4 Million.

Whenever a job runs , the memory consumption goes to 98% and the execution rate is extremely slow reaching one record per minute.The job is run through SSIS package.

I want to know what is causing the issue and any help on this

Comment: It is better to ask this question in https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Nothing else is slow, just that one SSIS package? Without any details of the package, it's nearly impossible to guess what could be the problem.